# Java Reflection: Difference between getMethods() and getDeclaredMethods()

Tags: java

Can someone please elaborate on this, and explain the difference between the two methods, and when/why you would want to use one over the others

Comment: Have you read the javadoc?

Comment: It's all in the Javadoc. `getMethods`: "Returns an array containing Method objects reflecting all the public methods of the class or interface represented by this Class object, including those declared by the class or interface and those inherited from superclasses and superinterfaces." `getDeclaredMethods`: "Returns an array containing Method objects reflecting all the declared methods of the class or interface represented by this Class object, including public, protected, default (package) access, and private methods, but excluding inherited methods."

Comment: Well, but there do exists ones like me ,who has read the java doc closely but just not clear about the semantic meaning of the doc, and all I need to make it through is some easy examples.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

`getDeclaredMethods` includes all methods declared *by the class itself*, whereas `getMethods` returns only public methods, but also those inherited from a base class (here from `java.lang.Object`).

Read more about it in the Javadocs for [`getDeclaredMethod`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods--) and [`getMethods`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods--).

Comment: "also" may suggest that `getMethods` returns additional elements to returned from `getDeclaredMethods`, which is not necessary true. It is worth mentioning that `getMethods` ignores non-public methods.

Comment: `getMethods` should be renamed `getPublicIncludingInheritedMethods`.

Answer (score 23):

### Short Version

| Method | Public | Non-public | Inherited |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `getMethods()` | ✔️ | ❌ | ✔️ |
| `getDeclaredMethods()` | ✔️ | ✔️ | ❌ |

### Long version

| Methods | getMethods() | getDeclaredMethods |
| --- | --- | --- |
| public | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| protected | ❌ | ✔️ |
| private | ❌ | ✔️ |
| static public | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| static protected | ❌ | ✔️ |
| static private | ❌ | ✔️ |
| default public | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| default protected | ❌ | ✔️ |
| default private | ❌ | ✔️ |
| inherited public | ✔️ | ❌ |
| inherited protected | ❌ | ❌ |
| inherited private | ❌ | ❌ |
| inherited static private | ✔️ | ❌ |
| inherited static protected | ❌ | ❌ |
| inherited static private | ❌ | ❌ |
| default inherited public | ✔️ | ❌ |
| default inherited protected | ❌ | ❌ |
| default inherited private | ❌ | ❌ |

If your goal, like mine, was to get **public** methods of a class:

| Method | Public | Non-public | Inherited |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `getMethods()` | ✔️ | ❌ | ✔️ |
| `getDeclaredMethods()` | ✔️ | ✔️ | ❌ |
| getPublicMethods() | ✔️ | ❌ | ❌ |

and nothing else:

| Methods | getPublicMethods() |
| --- | --- |
| public | ✔️ |
| protected | ❌ |
| private | ❌ |
| static public | ❌ |
| static protected | ❌ |
| static private | ❌ |
| default public | ❌ |
| default protected | ❌ |
| default private | ❌ |
| inherited public | ❌ |
| inherited protected | ❌ |
| inherited private | ❌ |
| inherited static private | ❌ |
| inherited static protected | ❌ |
| inherited static private | ❌ |
| default inherited public | ❌ |
| default inherited protected | ❌ |
| default inherited private | ❌ |

You have to do it yourself:

```
Iterable<Method> getPublicMethods(Object o) {
   List<Method> publicMethods = new ArrayList<>();

   // getDeclaredMethods only includes methods in the class (good)
   // but also includes protected and private methods (bad)
   for (Method method : o.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
      if (!Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers())) continue; //only **public** methods
      if (!Modifier.isStatic(method.getModifiers())) continue; //only public **methods**
      publicMethods.add(method);
   }
   return publicMethods;
}
```

Comment: Very good overview, thank you very much!